# Many Medias for One exercise in Sonata Media Bundle

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, sonata-media-bundle

I'm facing this weird problem with Sonata media bundle.

Basically, I have an exercise that can have many pictures.

My mapping of Exercice (it's French language) is :

```
 /**
  * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Application\Sonata\MediaBundle\Entity\Media", mappedBy="exercice")
  */
    private $medias;
```

Then I go to Application/Sonara/MediaBundle/Entity/Media.php and add a field $exercice:

```
namespace Application\Sonata\MediaBundle\Entity;

use Sonata\MediaBundle\Entity\BaseMedia as BaseMedia;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;


class Media extends BaseMedia
{
    /**
     * @var integer $id
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Acme\AcmeBundle\Entity\Exercice", inversedBy="medias")
     */
    private $exercice;
```

Weird things that happen :

1. When I run : `php app/console doctrine:generate:entities Application\Sonata\MediaBundle:Media`
   I don't see any setter or getter for Exercice inside Media entity.

   2. I get this error in profiler :

> The association Acme\AcmeBundle\Entity\Exercice#medias refers to
>   the owning side field
>   Application\Sonata\MediaBundle\Entity\Media#exercice which does not
>   exist.

The relevant part of config :

orm:
    auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
    auto_mapping: true
    mappings:
          ApplicationSonataMediaBundle: ~
          SonataMediaBundle: ~

What am I doing wrong ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Ok, found the solution.
I had to modify the mapping from the xml file :

```
src/Application/Sonata/MediaBundle/Resources/config/doctrine/Media.orm.xml
```

I added :

```
<many-to-one field="exercice" inversed-by="medias" target-entity="Acme\AcmeBundle\Entity\Exercice" />
```

and it's working just fine.